# MySQL Group by aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

Sorry if i sound total newbie but i know im one step away from solving this problem.
Is there any way that i can GROUP BY the `number_of_trans`? i would like to know **how many users have the same number of transaction, grouped by the number of transaction**. my query is like this:

```
SELECT
  cust_id, COUNT(*) AS number_of_trans
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  cust_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
  number_of_trans
```

the result im getting is like this

```
+------------------+--------------+
| cust_id          | numb_of_trans|
+------------------+--------------+
| 01               |  2           |
| 02               |  3           |
| 03               |  3           |
| 04               |  4           |
| 05               |  4           |
+------------------+--------------+
```

while im expecting a result like this:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| numb_of_trans    | count        |
+------------------+--------------+
| 1                |  null        |
| 2                |  1           |
| 3                |  2           |
| 4                |  2           |
| 5                |  null        |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Use your 1st query as a subquery (or CTE). Create a subquery or CTE which generates the list of values for the number of transactions which you are interested in (from 1 to 5 in shown case). Use these subqueries as tables in outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You could `left join` your current aggregate query with a list of numbers, and aggregate once more:

```
select 
    n.number_of_trans,
    count(*) cnt
from (
    select 1 number_of_trans
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
) n
left join (
    select count(*) as number_of_trans
    from mytable
    group by cust_id
    -- having count(*) > 1
) t on t.number_of_trans = n.number_of_trans
group by n.number_of_trans
order by n.number_of_trans
```

You can expand the `union all` subquery with more numbers if needed.

I am unsure that you do want a `having` clause in the aggregate query that filters out `cust_id`s that have just one entry, so I commented it - feel free to uncomment it as needed.

Also please note that this will yield `0` instead of `null` for `number_of_trans` that do not exist in the aggregate subquery. If you really want `null`, then you can do:

```
nullif(count(*), 0) cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below statement.

```
SELECT
number_of_trans, count(number_of_trans) as count FROM table GROUP BY number_of_trans ORDER BY number_of_trans.
```

Comment: number_of_trans is an alias for the aggregate functions, your solution is exactly what i wished it is. neverthless, thank you